# How to create copy link address menu on android?

Tags: java, android, url, webview, apk

I want to create a Browser app. I want to learn how to get the url of a hyperlink on webview, similar to chrome

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a CustomWebViewClient to achieve that.

You can even go to my android project which does exactly what you are wanting to do.

https://github.com/pbkn/wss/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/whysurfswim/wss/MainActivity.java

```
/**
     * CustomeWebViewClient used to load our main screen using webview
     */
    private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView webView, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            if (!isOnline()) {
                retryOnline();
            } else if (url.equals("https://whysurfswim.com/")) {
                textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.home_text));
            } else if (url.equals("https://whysurfswim.com/category/android-development/")) {
                textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.android_text));
            } else if (url.equals("https://whysurfswim.com/contact-us/")) {
                textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.contact_text));
            } else if (url.equals("https://whysurfswim.com/about-us/")) {
                textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.about_text));
            } else if (url.startsWith("https://whysurfswim.com/?s=")) {
                textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.search_result_text));
            } else if (url.startsWith("https://whysurfswim.com/")) {
                textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.post_text));
            } else {
                Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(viewIntent);
                webView.goBack();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView webView, String url) {
            if (!isOnline()) {
                retryOnline();
            }
            super.onPageFinished(webView, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageCommitVisible(WebView webView, String url) {
            if (!isOnline()) {
                retryOnline();
            }
            super.onPageCommitVisible(webView, url);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah you can do this easily if you want to get the current URL of webview use this code and copy it into the user's clipboard

I am assuming that you have set your WebViewClient.If not then you can do like below,

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        
        String currentUrl;
        
        private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
                @Override
         public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                    currentUrl= request.getUrl().toString();
        
        /// assuming that you have created a "copy link" button
        YourBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) 
 mContext.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
         ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("My url", currentUrl);
         clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
         Toast.makeText(mContext,"Copied from Clipboard!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
                    return  false;
                }
        }
```

make sure you have imported `android.content.ClipboardManager` and NOT the `android.text.ClipboardManager`. Latter is deprecated.

if you are in activity Replace `mContext` to `yourActivity.this` or if you are in fragment then replace it with `getContext()` this code gets the URL of your current page in webView and then stores it in `currentUrl` String and when your button is clicked then the link is copied into the user's clipboard.